# How do I prevent newly registered accounts from being automatically signed in?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

For my application, I got the usual registration option and the google authentication as well. At first, the registration is working well as intended, with no automatic sign-ins. But after integrating the google authentication in my code, my application would automatically sign-in the newly registered account even with these conditions on my login page. How do I fix this?

```
private void userLogin() {
    String emailtxt = email.getText().toString().trim();
    String passwordtxt = pass.getText().toString().trim();

    if(emailtxt.isEmpty()){
        email.setError("Email is required!");
        email.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailtxt).matches()){
        email.setError("Please enter a valid email!");
        email.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(passwordtxt.isEmpty()){
        pass.setError("Password is required!");
        pass.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(passwordtxt.length() < 6){
        pass.setError("Minimum password length is 6 characters!");
        pass.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailtxt, passwordtxt).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                //redirect to user profile

                if(user.isEmailVerified()) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));

                }
                else{
                    user.sendEmailVerification();
                    Toast.makeText(login.this, "Please check your email to verify your account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "Try again! The email/password you provided does not match any of our records", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my google auth code in the login activity

```
private void checkUser() {
    //if user is already signed in then go to profile activity
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "checkUser: Already logged in");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Google Signin intent result");
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> accountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            //google sign in success,
            GoogleSignInAccount account = accountTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogleAccount(account);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogleAccount(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogleAccount: begin firebase auth with google account");
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    //login success
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Logged In");

                    //get logged in user
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    //get user info
                    String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
                    String email = firebaseUser.getEmail();

                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Email: "+email);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: UID: "+uid);

                    //check if user is new or existing
                    if(authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser()){
                        //user is new account created
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Account Created...\n"+email);
                        Toast.makeText(login.this, "Account Created...\n"+email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        //existing user - logged in
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Existing user...\n"+email);
                        Toast.makeText(login.this, "Existing user...\n"+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //login failed
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Login Failed "+e.getMessage());

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: That is happening most likely because you aren't signing out the user. Here is a [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

In google sign-in code you check if the user is new or not but you are not doing anything with that other than showing a Toast.

```
//check if user is new or existing
if (authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser()) {
  //user is new account created.
  // if you want to do something with the new user do it here
  Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Account Created...\n" + email);
  Toast.makeText(login.this, "Account Created...\n" + email,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
  //existing user - logged in
  Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Existing user...\n" + email);
  Toast.makeText(login.this,"Existing user...\n" + email,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

If you want to do something if it's a new user do it inside the if statement and when a user signup using google his/her email already becomes verified.